# Update Group_Concat from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update 1 column with the results of concatenating several rows.
I am able to do it in a Select query but can't figure it out in an Update query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SizeTemp SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Table GROUP BY ParentSKU
```

Also, the result separates everything with a coma which is fine but I need the last string NOT to be followed by a coma. In the example below: no coma after XL

```
S,M,L,XL
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't put a comma after the last string, commas are just between values. Maybe you have a row where `SizeTemp` is an empty string, so it's putting the comma between `XL` and the empty string.

Comment: You could use `WHERE SizeTemp != ''` to exclude those values.

Comment: Thanks. I tried  WHERE SizeTemp != '' but it does not seem to work

Comment: I can't think of any other reason for it. Null values are automatically ignored in `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: This is what i have now: `UPDATE LAXSWebsite AS t1,
(SELECT ParentSKU, GROUP_CONCAT(SizeTemp SEPARATOR ', ') AS sizes FROM LAXSWebsite GROUP BY ParentSKU) AS t2
SET t1.attribute_pa_size = t2.sizes
WHERE t1.ParentSKU = t2.ParentSKU 
AND t1.SizeTemp != ''`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should be in the subquery that performs the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this. It seems like such a regressive step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `update` with inner query as shown below:

```
UPDATE TABLE AS t1,
(SELECT ParentSKU, GROUP_CONCAT(SizeTemp SEPARATOR ', ') AS sizes FROM TABLE GROUP BY ParentSKU) AS t2
SET t1.sizes = t2.sizes
WHERE t1.ParentSKU = t2.ParentSKU
AND t1.ParentSKU = ?
```

Criteria/column may differ based on which column needs updating.

Comment: This is Great. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work on SQlite database browser.